# Pandas data layout issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, pca

Trying to put an images pixel data into a pandas data frame to tun PCA across. I think I got it working but for some reason the layout is off. When I run the following code I get this result [image: my code]:

```
#read in image
img = cv2.imread('/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Stitched-Photos-for-Chris/p7_0015_20161005-949am-75m-pass-1.jpg.png',1)
row,col = img.shape[:2]
#print(row , col)

#get a unique pixel ID for each pixel

pixel = ['pixel-' + str(i) for i in range(0,row*col)]
bBand = ['bBand']
gBand = ['gBand']
rBand = ['rBand']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=[bBand,gBand,rBand],index = pixel)

#populate data for each band
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
data.loc[pixel,'bBand'] = b.flat[:]
data.loc[pixel,'gBand'] = g.flat[:]
data.loc[pixel,'rBand'] = r.flat[:]

print(data.head())
```

However, when I run the tutorial code I am basing this off I get the proper format:
[image]

```
genes = ['gene' + str(i) for i in range(1,101)]

wt = ['wt' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
ko = ['ko' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)]

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=[*wt,*ko],index = genes)

#create random data
for gene in genes:
    data.loc[gene,'wt1':'wt5'] = np.random.poisson(lam=rd.randrange(10,10000),size=5)
    data.loc[gene,'ko1':'ko5'] = np.random.poisson(lam=rd.randrange(10,10000),size=5)

print(data.head())
```

Trying to figure out if the extra gBand and rBand in the columns is an issuer or error that I have somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you are creating your columns incorrectly by making them a list

try:

```
pixel = ['pixel-' + str(i) for i in range(0,row*col)]

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['bBand','gBand','rBand'],index = pixel)

#populate data for each band
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
data.loc[pixel,'bBand'] = b.flat[:]
data.loc[pixel,'gBand'] = g.flat[:]
data.loc[pixel,'rBand'] = r.flat[:]

print(data.head())
```